# Can't see any services running in Ambari Web UI

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdpi

All of a sudden, there is no Ambari service shown on web UI. However, my YARN, HDFS, ZooKeeper, HBase services are running pretty well. Does anyone know why this happened? Thanks!

[image: current state]
[image: hdfs is running]

Comment: It seems that ambari is having trouble if the services work but are not shown. 1. What does your alert say? 2. Can you see other things (hosts, with/without services?)? 3. Have you tried restarting the ambari clients and server? 4. What did you change recently?

Comment: @daemon12 Restarting the ambari clients and server did not work. I finally found out that inconsistent data caused this. I wanted to remove some nodes from ambari server and I used the REST api to request a delete. However, I called removing node api before I deleted all the client. And this cause inconsistence between `hosts` table and `hostcomponentdesiredstate` table. After I remove the inconsistent rows and restart the server again. Everything went OK again.

Comment: Maybe, you wanted to address @Dennis above ;)

Comment: @zczhuohuo That sounds good. Please add it as an answer rather than a comment for better future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the cause. I used the REST api to remove some nodes from existing cluster. I did as the doc says. First stoped all the components on the nodes, then removed all the components(excluding installed clients) and finally removed the nodes. However, after doing all these things, the ambari database went into an inconsistent state. The `hostcomponentstate` and `hostcomponentdesiredstate` table contained deleted hosts entries which could not be found in `hosts` table. This leaded to when joining the `hosts` table and `hostcomponentstate`, we got a null HostEntity.

**After I deleted the inconsistent data on `hostcomponentstate` and `hostcomponentdesiredstate` table, every went well again.**

**So my opinion is should Ambari disable deleting node operation while there are still installed clients on the node, or should Ambari make a guarantee that the scenario I described never happens?**